# Find the limit $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos 4x}{x \tan 6x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

> Find: $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{1-\cos 4x}{x \tan 6x}.$$

My only idea is to multiply by $\frac{1+ \cos4x}{1+ \cos4x}$ to get $\sin^24x$ on the numerator, but can't figure how to follow up on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^24x}{16x^2}=1$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{6x}{\tan6x}=1,$ we can find that you have the limit if your expression approximation like $\frac{\left(\frac{1-(1-(4x)^2}{2}\right)}{x \times 6x}$ when $x$ is close enought to $0$.
And we have that limit is equivalent to $\frac{8x^2}{6x^2}$ and that is $\frac{4}{3}$.

From this, we can work it out and simplify to get

$$\frac{1-\cos4x}{x\tan6x}=$$

$$\frac{2\sin^22x\times\cos6x}{x\sin6x}=$$

$$2\times\left(2\times\frac{\sin2x}{2x}\right)^2\times\frac1{\dfrac{\sin6x}{6x}\times6}\times\cos6x=$$

$$\frac{2\sin^2(2x)\cot(6x)}{x}.$$

Since we know know that $\frac{2\sin^2(2x)\cot(6x)}{x}$ is the simplification of the trigonometric limit, we must take the limit of this result to find the answer to the once before limit.

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sin^2(2x)\cot(6x)}{x}=\boxed{\frac{4}{3}}.$$

To check your answer, graph the original function and you will find that as $x$ approaches $0$, the $y$ value should be $\frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: This is a great answer. It is very through and provides a very smooth approach. I think this should be the right answer. @Karl

Comment: you don't need to carry the innocent $\cos 6x$ along. you could set it to $1.$

Answer (score 2):

Using $\cos2A=1-2\sin^2A,$

$$\frac{1-\cos4x}{x\tan6x}=\frac{2\sin^22x\cdot\cos6x}{x\sin6x}=2\cdot\left(2\cdot\frac{\sin2x}{2x}\right)^2\cdot\frac1{\dfrac{\sin6x}{6x}\cdot6}\cdot\cos6x$$

Answer (score 2):

You can find approximate behavior of limit:
$\cos4x$ approximation is $1-(4x)^2/2+o(x^2)$.

$\tan(6x)$ approximation is $6x+o(x)$ when x close to 0.

Then you have:
lim if your expresion aproximate like $\frac{1-(1-(4x)^2/2)}{x*6x}$ when x close to 0
And we have that limit is equal to $ (8x^2)/(6x^2)$ and that is  4/3.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^24x}{16x^2}=1$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{6x}{\tan6x}=1.$